# flutter_ssh2 : PlatformException(upload_failure, The file path does not exist or is invalid., null, null)

Tags: flutter, ssh, sftp

i m trying to upload files from my phone's local storage to an SFTP server but i get an exception , even though the files exist and have read write permissions and the SSHclient is connected.

here is my code when going through the list of files :

```dart
`String? `sftpPath` = await `strg.Client.sftpUpload`(
                      path: `element.absolute.path`,
                      `toPath`: ".",
                      callback: (progress) async {
                        dev.log(
                            '(SFTP) file upload : ${element.path} progress : $progress');
                      });`
```

and here is my log :

```
[log] (SFTP)Client Connect : `session_connected`
[log] (SFTP) `sftpConnected` : true
[log] (SFTP) upload list length : 3
[log] (SFTP) element path : /data/user/0/com.example.app_13/files/rmt/2023-06-01T16:01:54.055876.png
[log] (SFTP) element exists : true
[log] (SFTP) element permissions rw-------
[log] (SFTP) `uploaderror` :`PlatformException(upload_failure, The file path does not exist or is invalid., null, null)`
```